# Auto scrolling of cursor on the R studio console

Tags: r, rstudio

When I execute my codes on the R console, you expect your codes to be executed and cursor to move on the very next line.

However, when I try and read a data in R, the cursor skips the very next line and jumps to the line after that.

The cursor keeps moving down automatically even if no codes are executed.

I cannot understand the reason for it. Posting two images to explain the same.

This is how it looks like on R console:

[image]

Comment: I only see one image .....

Comment: OS info, RStudio version, R version please.

Comment: Apologies. I have posted one image only.

Comment: R version-3.4.1, R studio version- 1.1.383, OS- Windows 8.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of research and experimentation, I discovered the bug to exist in the command `file.choose` which causes the addition of trailing spaces at regular intervals. Please try the same and validate my findings.

```
data<-file.choose()
```